# Template inheritance and sections without Blade syntax

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How to structure view hierarchy without using blade? What are the pure php counterparts  of blade directives (i,e `@section`, `@extend` , etc)?

Perhaps, something similar to  `<?php extend('foo') ?>`

In Phalcon framework, while it has its own template engine ([Volt](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html)) all of its template engine is also available in [pure PHP syntax](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html).

Comment: I have to ask - why??? I hope you dont think it is for performance, but there will be no gain (since Blade compiles into pure php as cached view files).

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Yeah, I know that. Our views are already available from previous version. Additionally, blade syntax is not much better that pure PHP and it add debugging harder. When there is an exception the error message point to compiled file not actual template.

Answer (score 7):

Since Blade directives just compile to normal PHP, it is technically possible to use the view structuring features without actually using Blade. I don't think it's very pretty though, and I personally would think twice about this decision.

You can find all the PHP code, Blade is compiled to, in this class:

[`Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php)

Here are some of them:

#### `@section('content')`

```
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
```

---

#### `@endsection`

```
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
```

---

#### `@extends('layout')`

This is a bit a tricky one. Usually Blade compiles it and then adds it to a footer variable which is printed at the bottom. So instead of putting it at the top (like you would with `@extends`) you have to place this at the end of your view:

```
<?php echo $__env->make('layout', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

---

#### `@yield('content')`

```
<?php echo $__env->yieldContent('content'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope there are some more clean alternatives.

Comment: There is a cleaner alternative: Blade (or any other templating system)

Comment: Making those function available in views is the cleaner way and indeed it is my question.

Comment: @lukasgeiter - Some might not consider throwing a template engine on top of another template engine to be cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

To put this in a pure PHP way you'll have to check out the `storage/framework/cache/views` and see what's happening there. Basically, is what Blade *compiles* to PHP code (instead of using @ and with proper function calls).

One way I can think is:

**In your template where you use `yield`**:

```
<!-- template.php -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- instead of using yield('container') -->
    <?php echo "_yield:container"; ?>
</div>
```

**In your file, instead of using `section` and `stop`**

```
<!-- view.php -->
<!-- instead of using extend('template') -->
<?php $templatePath = 'template.php'; ?>
<?php $sections = []; ?>
<!-- instead of using section('container') -->
<?php $currentSectionName = 'container'; ob_start(); ?>
    <p>This will be in my container div</p>
<!-- instead of using stop -->
<?php
    // get the current html
    $sections["_yield:".$currentSectionName] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    require($templateName);
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo str_replace($template,array_keys($sections),array_values($sections));
?>
```

Of course, this approach is simplistic at best. The code provided is not intended as a copy & paste solution, more like the concept.

Everything else is simple:

```
@foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    ...
@endforeach
```

translates to

```
<?php foreach($arr as $k=>$v) : ?>
    ...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That's how it's exactly done by the BladeCompiler. The same is with `if` and `while`.

Comment: have you tried this out? @Alex. seems like its not working for me

Comment: @FoggyMindedGreenhorn Just look for the view cache in the directory, Laravel is translating Blade to pure PHP in order for the PHP engine to be able to interpret this.

Comment: You are trying to echo an array, this dont work.

Answer (score 1):

The pure PHP equivalent to Blade is to split your code in sections like header and footer (for example) and then use require in your page to blend those sections in the corresponding place.

```
<?php
    require("template/header.php");
    // Here goes the body code
    require("template/footer.php");
?>
```

There is no pure PHP functions that i can think of, to extend a page from a main template, a you do using the yield directive.

Answer (score -1):

Blade compiles into PHP every time and what it compiles is stored in to `storage/framework/views/*`

The following link is a list of all things blade can compile to, you should be able to extract some knowledge out of this:

https://github.com/illuminate/view/blob/master/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php

The general idea for most templating engine is that they structure your code like so:

```
if ($condition):
  // do stuff
endif;

while ($condition):
  // do stuff
endwhile;

foreach ($array as $key => $value):
  // do stuff
endforeach;
```

For further reference, see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score -1):

Neither of blade directives is a 'pure' PHP function. PHP functions cannot start with @ and all blade directives do. In short, blade directives are shortcuts or synonyms to PHP built-in functions or control structures.

You are free to use any other template engine – it doesn't have to be Blade. Blade is built-in, but you are not locked to it. Just install a vendor package or make your own one, and return your HTML output with response, instead of using View facade.